# Where do glsl interpolation qualifiers go?

Tags: opengl, glsl

GLSL interpolation qualifiers can be used in various places: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers

But it isn't really explained whether they have to match (e.g. vertex out and fragment in) resp. what happens if they don't. The compiler does not seem to complain.

Comment: Note that information on qualifier matching does exist on the Wiki, just in [a different place](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Qualifier_matching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How interpolation qualifiers work with regard to interface matching has shifted in OpenGL over the various versions.

Pre-GL 4.3, interpolation qualifiers on inputs must match the corresponding output variable's interpolation qualifier from the preceding stage. Post-4.3, matching is unnecessary.

In both cases, it's reasonable to say that the only qualifiers the compiler will care about are the ones specified by the fragment shader's input variables. After all, in the pre-GL 4.3 case that requires exact matching, if the shader providing data to the FS uses a qualifier, the FS must use the same qualifier. And 4.3+, the standard explicitly says that only the fragment shader's qualifiers matter.

So if you want to know how a value will be interpolated, look at the fragment shader.

Answer (score 2):

The wiki may be incomplete.

If you read the [GLSL 4.6 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf), item 4.5, "Interpolation Qualifiers" you see:

> It is a link-time error if, within the same stage, the interpolation
>   qualifiers of variables of the same name do not match.

EDIT:

As @NicolBolas pointed out, "within the same stage" is not the case.

Again in the GLSL spec, item 4.3.4 "Input Variables" we can read:

> The  fragment  shader  inputs  form  an  interface  with  the  last 
>   active  shader  in  the  vertex  processing pipeline. For this
>   interface, the last active shader stage output variables and fragment
>   shader input variables  of  the  same  name  must  match  in  type  and
>   qualification,  with  a  few  exceptions:  The storage qualifiers must,
>   of course, differ (one is in and one is out). Also, interpolation
>   qualification (e.g.  flat)  and  auxiliary  qualification  (e.g. 
>   centroid)  may  differ.  These  mismatches  are  allowed between any
>   pair of stages. When interpolation or auxiliary qualifiers do not
>   match, those provided in  the  fragment  shader  supersede  those 
>   provided  in  previous  stages. If any such qualifiers 
>   are completely missing in the fragment shaders, then the default is
>   used, rather than any qualifiers that may  have  been  declared  in 
>   previous  stages.  **That  is,  what  matters  is  what  is  declared 
>   in  the fragment shaders, not what is declared in shaders in previous stages.**

Comment: "*within the same stage*" That doesn't mean *between stages*. It's basically saying that if you declare the same variable twice, it has to have the same qualifiers.